# Quadratic variation of the compensated Poisson process $N_t - \lambda t$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, poisson-process

> Consider a Poisson process $\{N_t, F_t\}_{0 \le t < \infty}$. Then the martingale $M_t = N_t - \lambda t$ has quadratic variation $\lambda t$.

The quadratic variation of $M$ is defined here as the unique natural increasing process in the Doob-Meyer decomposition of $M^2$. So it suffices to show that $M_t^2 - \lambda t$ is a martingale.

Fix $s<t$. We have $\mathbb{E}[N_t -\lambda t | F_s] = N_s - \lambda s$, so 
$\mathbb{E}[N_t | F_s] = N_s - \lambda s + \lambda t.$  Using this, and the independence of $N_t - N_s$ to the filtration $F_s$, we have to show that 
$$
\mathbb{E}[N_t^2 - 2\lambda t N_t + \lambda^2 t^2 | F_s]
 = N_s^2 -2\lambda s N_s + \lambda^2 s^2.
$$

First, 
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[N_t^2 |F_s]
 &= \mathbb{E}[(N_t-N_s+N_s)^2|F_s] \\
 &= \mathbb{E}[(N_t-N_s)^2|F_s] + 2\mathbb{E}[(N_t-N_s)N_s|F_s] + N_s^2 \\
 &= \mathbb{E}[(N_t-N_s)^2] + 2N_s \mathbb{E}[N_t - N_s]+N_s^2 \\
 &= 2\lambda(t-s) + 2\lambda(t-s) N_s + N_s^2.
\end{split}
$$

Using this, I get 
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[N_t^2 - 2\lambda t N_t + \lambda^2 t^2 | F_s]
 &= N_s^2 + 2\lambda(t-s)N_s + 2\lambda(t-s) -2\lambda t(N_s - \lambda s + \lambda t) +\lambda^2t^2 \\
&= N_s^2 -2\lambda sN_s + 2\lambda t - 2 \lambda s + 2 \lambda^2 ts - \lambda^2 t^2.
\end{split}
$$

So I don't get the desired identity. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @gt6989b $N_t - N_s$ is independent of $F_s$.

Comment: One thing I see is that you have $\mathbb{E}[(N_t - N_s)^2]$ wrong - this is a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda(t-s)$. For a $\mathrm{Poiss}(\mu)$ RV, the second moment is $\mu^2 + \mu,$ not $2\mu$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Oh my stupid mistake from me. That solves it.

Comment: $-\lambda t$ and $-\lambda s$ are missing on each side in the equality you try to show.

Answer (score 3):

Since the expectation and the variance of $N_t-N_s$ are both equal to $\lambda(t-s)$ and since
the increments of $N$ are independent we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[(N_t-N_s)^2|{\cal F}_s]=\mathbb{E}[(N_t-N_s)^2]=\underbrace{\lambda(t-s)}_{\text{variance}}+\underbrace{\lambda^2(t-s)^2}_{\big(\mathbb E[N_t-N_s]\big)^2}\,.\tag{1}
$$

- OP had this wrongly as $2\lambda(t-s)\,.$

Using (1) and
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[N_t|{\cal F}_s]&=\mathbb E[N_t-\lambda t|{\cal F}_s]+\lambda t=N_s-\lambda s+\lambda t\,,\tag{2}
\end{align}
we get
\begin{align}
\\[2mm]
\mathbb{E}[N_t^2 |{\cal F}_s]
 &= \mathbb{E}[(N_t-N_s+N_s)^2|{\cal F}_s] \\[2mm]
 &= \mathbb{E}[(N_t-N_s)^2|{\cal F}_s] + 2\,\mathbb{E}[(N_t-N_s)N_s|{\cal F}_s] + N_s^2 \\[2mm]
 &= \mathbb{E}[(N_t-N_s)^2] + 2\,N_s\,\mathbb{E}[N_t - N_s]+N_s^2 \\[2mm]
 &= \underbrace{\lambda(t-s)+\lambda^2(t-s)^2}_{(1)} + 2\lambda(t-s) N_s + N_s^2\,\tag{3}
\end{align}
and

\begin{align}\require{cancel}
&\mathbb E[(N_t-\lambda t)^2|{\cal F}_s]=\mathbb E[N_t^2-2\lambda tN_t+\lambda^2t^2|{\cal F}_s]\\[2mm]
&=\underbrace{\lambda(t-s)+\lambda^2(t-s)^2 + 2\lambda(t-s) N_s + N_s^2}_{(3)}-2\lambda t\underbrace{\big(N_s-\lambda s+\lambda t\big)}_{(2)}+\lambda^2t^2\\[2mm]
&=\lambda(t-s)+\lambda^2(t-s)^2 + 2\lambda(\bcancel{t}-s) N_s + N_s^2-\bcancel{2\lambda tN_s}-2\lambda^2t(t-s)+\lambda^2t^2\\[2mm]
&=\lambda(t-s)+\lambda^2(t-s)^2 \underbrace{- 2\lambda s N_s + N_s^2}_{(*)}-2\lambda^2t(t-s)+\lambda^2t^2\\[2mm]
&=\lambda(t-s)+\lambda^2(\cancel{t^2}-\bcancel{2ts}+\xcancel{s^2})+\overbrace{(N_s-\lambda s)^2-\xcancel{\lambda^2s^2}}^{(*)}
 -2\lambda^2(\cancel{t^2}-\bcancel{ts})+\cancel{\lambda^2t^2}\\[2mm]
&=\lambda(t-s)+(N_s-\lambda s)^2\,.
\end{align}
This shows that $(N_t-\lambda t)^2-\lambda t$ is a martingale and therefore
$\langle N\rangle_t=\lambda t\,.$