# Characterization of compensated Poisson processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, poisson-process

I've found the following statement (but it is rather an example) in a book that states if $X$ is a local martingale and its quadratic variation has the form

$$\left[X\right]=t+cX$$

where $c$ is a constant, then $X$ is a compensated Poisson process. The example wanted to emphasize the similarity between this formula and the Levy characterization of a Brownian motion.

However this formula just doesn't seem right. Let $\pi$ denotes a Poisson process with $\lambda$ intensity parameter, so $X\dot{=}\pi-\lambda t$ is a compensated Poisson process. This way

$$\left[X\right]=\left[\pi-\lambda t\right]=\left[\pi\right]=\pi\neq t+c\left(\pi-\lambda t\right).$$

Can we somehow correct this formula or do I just miss something trivial here? Is there any similar formula for compensated Poisson processes?

Comment: Looks [wrong](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282210/is-there-any-analogous-to-levy-characterization-theorem-for-purely-discontinuous). Where is that from?

Comment: In a textbook written by our teacher. However he mentioned that this book is the first version and may be full of with errors (...so this is probably one of them). However I stil lbelive this formula can be amended

Comment: Good luck to your teacher. I just wrote a self-contained [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464566/quadratic-variation-of-the-compensated-poisson-process-n-t-lambda-t/4874048#4874048) for the well-known fact that the *predictable* quadratic variation of $X$ is $\langle X\rangle_t=\lambda t\,.$ Perhaps your teacher means that with $c=0$ and $\lambda=1\,.$ Of course, as you say, the (non predictable) quadratic variation $[X]_t$ is $\pi_t$ (usually written as $N_t\,$).